# Add Smarty Page

Tags: templates, smarty

We used the smarty template engine as the framework for my site. I am trying to add static pages to the site, but I cannot get the **new static pages** to appear.

**Can someone please tell me what I need to do to get a new page to appear?**

Here is an example. My About Us Page is located at www.domain.com/about. This page is called about.tpl

I want to add another page called 'history'. The page is saved as history.tpl. I FTP'd the page to my server, but when I go to www.domain.com/help it does not appear.

I feel like I'm missing some sort of important step to get the help.tpl page to appear.

Comment: Smarty is a template engine to PHP. You can't just upload a file and expect it to show up. It has to be referenced from the PHP code somewhere

Comment: There is a whole lot that could be going on here depending on your smarty setup. Have you not added a page to your site before? Would need more info on your site. But in the PHP files can be display like this `$smarty->display('help.tpl');`

Comment: That is correct, I have not added a page to my site. I have added html pages to the site, but never the smarty pages. I have noticed that each tpl page is referenced in the php page. For example, we have a a couple tpl files for home. - home_logged_out.tpl and home_logged_in.tpl. The php file is called home.php. This files seems to two lines of code, which make reference to both tpl files  $smarty->display('home_logged_out.tpl'); and $smarty->display('home_logged_in.tpl');

Comment: So based on the above..my guess is that I need to create a php file for the 'history.tpl' and then add the line of code to history.php that connects history.php to history.tpl so that history.tpl will show?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind smarty is a template engine for PHP. You can't just upload a template file and expect your homepage to show this without any reference, you at least need a few lines of PHP code to load and display it.

The [basic setup for using a smarty template](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl) is something like this:

```
<?php

require_once(YOUR_SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->display('your_template.tpl');

?>
```

If you have some script like this, call it maybe `about.php`, upload it, then go to `www.yoursite.com/about.php`, the template `your_template.tpl` will be displayed, if configured correctly.